# User must exist in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My form partial is as follows:

```
<%= form_with(model: guitar, local: true) do |form| % >
<% if guitar.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(guitar.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this 
   guitar from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% guitar.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
<div class="form-group">
<%= form.label :title %>
<%= form.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<%= form.label :description %>
<%= form.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<%= form.submit "Create New Guitar Lesson", class: "btn btn-primary" 
 %>

  </div>


   <% end %>
```

When I try to create a new entry in a table via a form, an error message pops up 'user must exist', which is fine by me.

How do I auto insert (which file / section should I place the code in) current logged in user ID to the form in the background without having the user keying it in manually?

I've pushed the entire app up to the cloud at http://github.com/cheese1884/197451 –

Comment: http://github.com/cheese1884/197451 
One user can have many guitars and many guitars belong to 1 user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many way to implement this, as i understand you have an user_id field in Guitar model.

Simple solution is need to attach user_id into Guitar object on create action.

In `GuitarController` go for `create` and add this line. `.merge(user_id: current_user.id)`.

Remember User must be signed in to get `current_user` object.

*Sample*:

```
@g = Guitar.new(guitar_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))
```

**Edited**

You have many bugs there, 1st of all you need to clean up your controllers.

*ApplicationController*: remove lines between 6-18. No need it, because Devise gem will provide you these features already.

*GuitarsController*:

```
def guitar_params
   params.require(:guitar).permit(:name, :description)
end

// guitar view from
<div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
</div>


// models/user.rb

  //add this line
  has_many :guitars
```

Comment: still getting the same error of 'user must exist'. Ref https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lJ3KXMAW0AwVkYhKKQss2NWf5G-gYuSENZS27WLoHf0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: and another error after submitting the form which says "too few arguments". Ref https://ibb.co/bC0d2U

Comment: @songs can u post yr Guitar Model (guitar.rb), and Schema ?

Comment: @songs remove `:user_id`  from `guitar_params ` and change it to `guitar_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id)` looks like everything fine for me

Comment: tried but gotten error undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass. Updated Git accordingly to reflect what you proposed

Comment: ok, yr `current_user` object is empty. Because, you are overwriting current_user object by devise in `application_controller` remove lines from 6-18 where `current_user, signed_in?, and admin_signed_in?` methods and keep rest of parts

Comment: latest code pushed and changes you proposed are also there! :)

Comment: After record is successfully created, i noticed the memory location of user keeps changing, the part with the random characters. Correct me if I'm wrong on this. Do I need to be concerned on this change every time? E.g. 1st save yielded User: #<User:0x00007fe3a76462b0>. 2nd save yielded User: #<User:0x00007fe3a2df4a98>

Comment: How do I hide the user memory's location from the show view? I've pushed all the latest code to the same repo FYI.

Comment: @songs `<%= @guitar.user.email %>` its actually yr user object. So do whatever  you want with it. Like show owner email or name or etc...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your field in table is called user_id and you are using Devise.

You should insert the following in your form

```
<%= form.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
```

The user's id (taken from Devise's current_user) will be prepopulated in a hidden field that they won't be able to see.

Answer (score 2):

As per doc mentioned of user model

app/models/guitar.rb

```
class Guitar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :guitars
end
```

In rails 5 [belongs_to association required by default](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html)
which means at the time of creation of each record of `guitar` `user_id` is required.

So here by at controller you can solve it by: -

In devise after sign_in there is a helper method which `current_user` which is current logged_in user

in `guitars_controller.rb`

```
def create
  new_guitar_record = current_user.guitars.new(guitar_params)
  if new_guitar_record.save
    #guitar created successfully for current logged in user
  else
    #current_user.guitar.errors.full_messages
  end
end

def guitar_params
  params.require(:guitar).permit(:name, :description)
end
```

Please amend `controllers/application_controller` as you have messed up devise's current_user and your custom current_user

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

Note: - You can also pass `current_user.id` by `hidden_field :user_id` with guitar form but as per security concern it's not good, as user can invoke any `user_id` via browser.

Comment: used your solution but gotten the error undefined method `guitar' for nil:NilClass. REF https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iWLwrBODm8swfBXD3CjbLtEfPs_A98v-eqWIMQsc9Z0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @songs In that case i believe user is not logged in which means that curren_user is nil, are you sure that user is logged_in before create guitar? can you show guitars_controller#create?

Comment: I've pushed the entire app up to the cloud at https://github.com/cheese1884/197451

Comment: Thanks again for the trouble @Gabbar

Comment: @songs as I see everything is fine except two things from strong parameters remove `user_id` and `current_user.guitar.create()` as I mentioned in answer and it should work if user is logged in . Please try again and let me know for further guidance.

Comment: Sorry which spots exactly? I'm still kinda new to Rails. Did you mean the def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :description)
    end in the User's controller?

Comment: the issue seem to have been solved by advise of another user. I've pushed the latest code again. I hope it's fine now.

Comment: added has_many :guitars in user.rb, deleted all the entries in application_controller to have just class, protect_from_forgery and end & the other solutions as well, but gotten error 'Cannot redirect to nil!'. I'm positive I'm signed in.

Comment: After record is successfully created, i noticed the memory location of user keeps changing, the part with the random characters. Correct me if I'm wrong on this. Do I need to be concerned on this change every time? E.g. 1st save yielded User: #<User:0x00007fe3a76462b0>. 2nd save yielded User: #<User:0x00007fe3a2df4a98>

Comment: That's not for concern it's just a object memory reference. So it's different for different object. 2nd things can you explain what exactly you arw getting error on successful creation of guitar record ?

Comment: I  gotten error 'Cannot redirect to nil!'. Now, i wish to hide the memory location. Do you know how I can do that or should I open a new question where you can answer this? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sign in a user in the background, use the `sign_in` helper inside your controller's action:

```
sign_in(:user, user)
```

Comment: my users' table. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1b17QLn-nNa2Hc2h9wu6fB1Eyf-vFgGqi01DjjDyYUUA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry for not being clear. :( The user has to be logged in, to see the form. But how do I get the form to grab the current logged in user's ID as the error states user must exist. Thanks again